# Delete file by filename on FTP with Java

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

Is it possible to delete file by filename, without the extension. I'm using FTPClient to connect to my FTP server and work great. I can upload files only in 3 formats (.png, .jpg, .gif). In fact i could delete the file only if i specify the extension like that and work:

```
ftp.deleteFile("/"+productID+setFileName+".png");
```

But i want to delete the file no matter what is the extension of the file, only by file name. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to delete file from ftp server using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790783/how-to-delete-file-from-ftp-server-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [startsWith()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) function?

```
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient ftpClient=new FTPClient();  //instantiate the FTPClient
FTPFile[] ftpFiles=ftpClient.listFiles();//get the list of files in the root directory of the FTP server
for(FTPFile tempFtpFile:ftpFiles)
{
  //go through the list of files and delete those that start with your required prefix
  String tempFtpFileName=tempFtpFile.getName();
  if(tempFtpFileName.startsWith(productID+setFileName))
   ftpClient.deleteFile(tempFtpFile.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your ftp client has implemented the ftp command `mdelete`.

AFAIK `mdelete` accepts wildcard. Or if your server accepts wildcard when execute deletion commands.

Had you tried to execute:

```
ftp.deleteFile("/"+productID+setFileName+".*");
```